# Eclipse To AndroidStudio - Unable to get the right ProjectStructure

Tags: android, eclipse, migration, structure

what I've got is a really big Android Project, orginially developed in Eclipse ADT. I now trying to migrate this project to Android Studio. The point arrived where I am about to desperate...

```
project2android
- .idea/
- ActionBarSherlock-4.2/    <- normal folder - NO MODULE after import
- async/                    <- normal folder - NO MODULE after import
- project2android/          <- normal folder - NO MODULE after import
- project2android-test/     <- normal folder - NO MODULE after import
- gradle/
- play_licensing/           
- .gitignore
- project2android.iml
- build.gradle/
- gradlew
- gradlew.bat
- local.properties
```

I want to make "ActionBarSherlock-4.2", "async", "project2android" and "project2android-test" Android Studio Modules. The main problem is that Android Studio generated an empty (!) build.gradle file at the root-level. No one of the named subfolders got any build.gradle file.

**What did I try?**

1. I first exportet the Project from Eclipse as Gradle Export and Imported it into Android Studio. You see the result above.
2. I created Default-Projects in AndroidStudio + some Submodules and tried to copy the generated build.gradle files into the project to migrate. This did not work as Android Studio shows errors on some line of the build.gradle files.
3. Tried to find other solutions in StackOverFlow etc. with the result that no of those concrete cases really fit on mine as the project structure given by the original Eclipse Project is somehow extraordinary...
4. After hours of rebasing, pulling, try and error and a lot of frustration I started to read the migration guide (http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html)... but I am pretty overstrained with all the content.
5. Finally I tried at least to manually copy the project2android-test/ subfolder into project2android/ as AndroidStudio wants it to be there... but then I lost dependencies to assets...

There must be a way to quickly adopt what I try to do without getting a gradle-specialist...

I appreciate any help.

Comment: which android studio version you using?

Comment: @Pavan I am using version: 1.2.2

Comment: did you get import project(eclipse) option because in  new version you have to just import the project which configured in eclipse rest studio will do for you

Comment: In my special case the import function of eclipse projects import the Eclipse-Subprojects in the wrong hierarchie and fails to create build.gradle files... thats why I was asking. cheers

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time figuring out how to migrate correctly to Android Studio and I achieved my goal by setting up the project step by step.

If someone got similar problems I will post the "Step by Step"-Instructions but only if somebody really wants... because I need to translate it first and its quite a lot text.

Greetings